# Display images from folder on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET website using C#. I've only ever used classic ASP before so I'm having quite a steep learning curve. It's been recommended that I use MVC4 for the website.

There needs to be a user login and each login will relate to a filepath which has images in it.  When the user has logged in and navigates to the images section, all of the images from their filepath should be displayed.

The users and the filepath for each user will be stored in a SQL Server database in a table called `login`. To keep it simple the login table would look like:

```
create table login (
    username varchar(10), 
    password(varchar(10), 
    filepath(varchar(200))
```

Example data:

```
Username: testUser
Password: password
Filepath: ../Images/testUser/
```

The folder holding the images will always be the same as the username. Is this something that is doable? I've tried some Google searches but can't seem to find the solution.

Hope someone can help / point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can do it with handlers or global.asax routing.

Comment: What is it that you're having problems with? The storage of the user data or the display of the images?

Comment: Displaying the images, i'm not too sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Alex , Its Doable ..

You need to create Directories when  the user Signups , ( Of-course , you need to pre-check whether the directory name already exists .. I recommend creating a Different directory for your users , rather than using Root directory ) 

For Creating directory you can use ..

```
string path = "yourCustomUserDirectory;
if(!Directory.Exists(path))
 {
 Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Next you need to set the Session Variable for User to point to your Users Directory who has Logged in .. 

This Will help in maintaining ,, ahh session , so that user only Updates , deletes or adds to his own directory across web-pages

You Can Find all the files  in the Directory by ..

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(userDirectory);
foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
    ProcessFile(fileName);
```

In the ProcessFile Method you can use [HtmltextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .. 

Also Refer this Link , it has an example for doing exactly that .. 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmltextwriter

Comment: you might want to look into this too ..

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26101/Problem-with-Response-Write-Changing-Dynamic-Conte